How to configure splunk syslog with .net 8 api application using nlog logging
I already have syslog endpoint and indexer. I have created a .net 8 application and for logging I am using nlog.
Currently my logs are stored in text files but I want to forward my log to splunk enterprise.
Need suggestions or .net code to configure syslog with my .net api application.
Need help to configure syslog with my .net application using nlog to log the exception into splunk enterprise.

You can use NLog for writing to a JSON-file and have Splunk Forwarder to send it. You can write directly to Splunk using http. You can use the NLog SysLog Target.
